# How to open sftp panel in MobaXterm if the server prints strings when I login?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sftp

As I know, Sftp will not work if the startup scripts of the server echo any kind of output. 
  (reference : http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html#6_8_2)

But if I am not the superuser of the server, how can I activate my sftp panel when or after I login ?

(I have make sure that if there is no echo script, I can open sftp panel.)

Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to open a SFTP session explicitly. Go to Sessions > New session and select SFTP. This will open a SFTP session as a tab in the central window of MobaXterm. If this doesn’t work, I doubt you’d be able to get a SFTP panel.

I am not sure the web page you linked points to the problem of yours. If this was a keyboard-interactive issue, you would still get a SFTP dialog box asking for the password after you have been connected to SSH (obviously I’m assuming your are trying to connect with SSH). If you hit Cancel with this dialog box, MobaXterm still tries to connect with SCP.

Comment: I think you are right, since when I added an comment "echo "hello"", MobaXterm still can pop up the SFTP panel (which is located on left of MobaXterm window) and I can explicitly connect with SFTP  only.
Thank you for your answer! Maybe there is someting I didn't notice...@@